# How can I make pygame use a specific input device as the mouse?

Tags: input, pygame, linux

I am working on (not really a game, but it's using pygame so I hope my question is on topic here).

The program appears to be looking at `/dev/input/event0`, which is random USB mouse, just like the desktop environment and everything else is. But what I need is for `pygame.mouse` to be "connected" (not sure of the right word here) to `/dev/input/event2`, which is the USB touchscreen.

I've figured these two paths out by using `evtest /dev/input/event2` and seeing which one responds to being fingered but I have not figured out how to configure pygame to look at the right one, is there a way or is this hardwired somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is controlled by environment variables.

You need to set `SDL_FBDEV`, which controls which framebuffer to use. Then, you can use `SDL_MOUSEDEV` to control which device to use for the mouse.

Something like this:

```
SDL_FBDEV=/dev/fb0 SDL_MOUSEDEV=/dev/input/event2 sudo python3 muffin.py
```

(I haven't yet figured out why I need sudo here to use that framebuffer. It has 660 perms and I'm a member of the `video` group, so maybe some other process is interfering somehow)

Comment: Now I just need to figure out why X and Y axes are swapped.